# Pass extra parameters from ebs to apex

Tags: apex, oracle-ebs

I have integrated Oracle EBS with APEX using the launchapex.jsp, which helps in retreiving all the session values from EBS to APEX page.

Now, I also want few other extra values like entity id etc. to be passed as parameters from EBS to APEx. Where and how can I do that. Can you please help.

Comment: Not clear which launchapex.jsp you are referring to - are you using the one from here? http://donaldmclarke3.blogspot.com/2014/08/custom-ebs-to-apex-integration-part-2.html

Are you looking to drill in from an existing page that has these other parameters?

Comment: I am using LAunchApex.jsp from the website : http://info.insum.ca/insum-ebs-apex-integration-package. I am able to access EBS session variables using this JSP..but not sure how to pass other values like Entity Id or any other ID related to the page eg. Expense ID, PO Number etc.